# How to take xml variation for php

Tags: php, xml

I have a xml. I take all data but I need some value.

```
 <stock>
 <Ozellik isim="color">Black</Ozellik>

 <Ozellik isim="size">Standart Size</Ozellik>
 </stock>
```

I write this code

```
$varozellik[$r] = $Urun->Stoklar->Stok[$i]->Ozellik[$r]
```

and turn back to me only - Black 
                           Standart Size

But I need color or size? How to take ?

Thank you

Comment: Show more of your xml, your code, what you get, what you want. This will make it easier for people to understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

use `xpath` to select a specific `Ozellik` node by its `isim` attribute value:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$size = $xml->xpath("/stock/Ozellik[@isim='size']")[0];
```

The `xpath` expression will select

- all `Ozellik` children of `stock`
- having an `isim` attribute with the value of 'size'. Conditions are in `[]`, and the `@` is for attribute.
- `xpath` returns an array of `SimpleXml` elements, so in order to get a scalar value, we dereference the array and take its first value by `[0]`at the end of the line. Note this takes PHP >= 5.4.

see it working: https://eval.in/493083

Please note that the above code will select **all** matching nodes in your XML, even across multiple `<stock>` nodes.